# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it./ while converting ArrayList<Float>

Tags: database, arraylist, kotlin, typeconverter

Error was made when I will try to save `ArrayList<Float>` as column in room database

```
   @Entity(tableName = "Height")
class Height: Serializable {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Long = 0

  @ColumnInfo(name = "data")
  var data: ArrayList<Float>? = ArrayList()
}
@Dao
abstract class HeightDao : BaseDao<Height>() {

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  abstract fun insertAllHeight(listOfHeight: ArrayList<Float>)
```

I have written TypeConverter

```
    @TypeConverter
fun fromArrayListOfFloats(list: ArrayList<Float>?): String {
    return list?.joinToString(separator = ";") { it.toString() } ?: ""
}

    @TypeConverter
fun toArrayListOfFloats(string: String?): ArrayList<Float> {
    return ArrayList(string?.split(";")?.mapNotNull { it.toFloatOrNull() } ?: emptyList())
}
```

It works fine, when I am convering `ArrayList<SomeEntityObject>`, but in this case it makes an above error. Please, help!